# How does a Neural Network calculate the sum of the weights?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have been reading about Neural Networks in general and trying to understand the basic theory behind it. I am getting a bit confused and wondering if someone could help me out.

The way I understand Neural Networks is as follows:

Input layer + hidden layers + output layers, where each layer has nodes, or neurons. Each Neuron obtains input from all neurons in the previous layer and also send to each neuron in the next layer. Then it is said that the neuron calculates the sum of the weights and then utilises an activation function to either fire or not (or send a number between 0 and 1).

What gets me confused is HOW it calculates the sum of the weights?

[image: Simple Neural Network with one hidden layer]

In the figure above I have created a simple neural network and called the input as Andrew Ng does in his lectures (Youtube).

So, take neuron a1 in layer 1: 
This will get the value a1 and a2 from layer 0, and also the corresponding weights and biases, which will be gathered in the vectors b1 and w1 for layer 1.

Is the sum then calculated from the following formula? 
z = w1*x + b? Is this in general for all Neural Networks or is this just one single type of NN? Will z1 in layer 1 also be a vector? Is it the activation function which makes it a scalar?

I understand that there are different activation functions which calculate the final scalar value which is sent to the next layer of neurons together with weights and biases. But I guess I am very confused about the weights and biases and where they come from/are calculated etc.

I hope my explanation wasn't too confusing, because I am pretty confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The operation z1 = w1*x + b is just for fully connected layers. [Convolutional Neural Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network), for instance, use different operations.

I think there is a bit of confusion with the notation. The value of a1 in layer 1 is a scalar, and to get this you need to apply the activation function to another scalar, z1, which can be calculated z1 = w1*x + b. Here, w1 is not a matrix, but a vector of the weights that go to the neuron a1.

However, this is not the usual way to do the computations, as this does not take the advantage of vectorization. In general, you want to do z = W*x + b, where W is the matrix of all the weights and z is a vector, and then apply the activation function element-wise, obtaining a vector of activations for that layer, a.

Comment: Okay, so z1 is a scalar, that helps a lot! So if I call the previous neurons x1, x2 and x3, would the first neuron in the next layer do this: 
z1 = (w1*x1) + (w1*x2) + (w1*x3) + b1? So it sums up all contributions and has a bias?

Comment: Sort of, but not exactly: The expression should be z1 = (w1*x1) + (w2*x2) + (w3*x3) + b, where w1, w2 and w3 are the weights that go from x1, x2 and x3 to z1. But the idea is right: sum the contributions and add a bias.

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot! It's all just a bit confusing. So, this method only covers fully connected neural networks, right?

Comment: Exactly, there are other architectures like CNN and RNN (Recurrent Neural Networks), but all of them have some layers that are fully connected, so hopefully understanding this you help you understand other architectures as well. Can you give my answer the label of answer of the question?

Answer (score 2):

You can think of the weights as the arrows that connect your neurons. For every neuron in a layer, you have a weight for every neuron in the next layer. That means you can use one matrix between two layers to store the weights.

To calculate the values of the next layer neurons, you do this:

For every node in the second layer, you calculate `z1[0] = w1*a1[0] + w2*a2[0] + w3*a3[0]`. This will be a scalar value. Now you can apply the sigmoid function that will squash the scalar (but it will still be a scalar).

Instead of doing this for every single neuron, we can use a vectorized implementation and calculate all values for a whole layer at once:

```
z[1] = a[0] * layer1_weights
a[1] = sigmoid(z[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Look this playlist. You learn how to implement your on nn.

[Shiffmann Coding Train Neurol Network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XJ7HLz9VYz0&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6aCibgK1PTWWu9by6XFdCfh),
[Feedforward Algorithm Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qWK7yW8oS0I&index=12&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6aCibgK1PTWWu9by6XFdCfh)

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider all the numbers here as matrix. Your input a[0] is a 1x3 matrix i.e., a column vector. Now, as you had mentioned, without a activation function for a layer, the layer output would be a[1] = a[0].w[01] + b[1], where w[01] weight between 0th layer and 1st layer. Similarly b[1] is the bias added to the first layer.

So, for matrix multiplication, your w[01] would be a 3x4 matrix and the bias will be a 1x4 matrix. 
If let's say you had a sigmoid activation to this later, in this case, sigmoid function will be applied to your a[1] to obtain the final output from this layer. 
It is always easier to understand the operations of NN using matrix! 
Hope that helps!